# Is it safe to sand sharp edges off of this manufactured desk?

Tags: finishing, sanding, mdf

I bought this desk recently from Amazon. The edge of the desk is a little sharp for my liking so I'm thinking about buying a fine sandpaper (320 grit?) to sand it down a little.

Is this safe to do?  I asked chat gpt and it said it was safe just want a second opinion.

[Link to Amazon product page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C73BXBTS)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking! Are you referring to the powder coating? This is an on *the metal components only*, powder coating is electrostatically applied, then baked to melt the powder. It is basically only used on metal. So we'll need to change the title and body of the Q for this to be wood-related and on-topic for the stack.

Comment: So I presume it's the edges of the top that are the issue? I can't see where it says anything about the finish but it's stated to be MDF (made from wood fluff bonded with resin, heat and pressure), with a faux-wood laminate glued to the faces. The sharp edges are an unknown because there are multiple ways these are handled, and the product pics don't show them clearly enough to be unequivocal. But based on the fact of them being sharp they should be sandable; it would help if you could take one or two clear photos showing edges and a corner so we can see them clearly.

Comment: I don't recommend sanding. The laminate is bound to be thin, and the wood grain effect will only be on the top face of the laminate layer, so any sanding will probably expose substrate.  In addition, any variance in the width/depth of the sanding will show as a varying thickness contrasting line.

Comment: Agree that it's probably a thin veneer/laminate. If you really had to make it rounded, I'd get a router with a roundover bit and make a feature out of it.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, huh???? Roundover bit for easing edges on *laminate*? Does not compute.

Comment: @graphus — not sure what to say… the roundover bit will cut a wide corner, taking out both the top laminate and the edging and showing the underlying mdf. It’ll be rounded but really obvious (and would want some sort of protective finish). Should I run a sample and post a pic?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, that is what I thought you mean..... just couldn't figure out why anyone would do that, like, ever LOL

Comment: At least you didn't just trust the _artificial_ intelligence and decided to ask actual humans.

Answer (score 3):

I'm used to similar desks not having the fake wood right to the edge, but instead having a wood-ish colour curve, that also means the edge isn't harsh.  On the one I'm sitting at it's clearly that the plastic veneer on the edges is rather thick (about 1.5mm) and rounded to a nice smooth edge.  The one in your picture looks like it should be similar.

[image: plastic veneer on a desk]

You might try to replicate that effect, but I'd try it on the back edge and corners first. Testing on the underneath edges is also an option although the underside may not   have the same finish as the more visible faces, so may feel different.

I'd also aim to take off the minimum material to just barely achieve what you're aiming for.  Some of these finishes can be very thin; they're the ones most likely to have an unpleasant edge.  To that end (if it didn't look unsightly tested at the back) I'd use a wooden sanding block with the sandpaper stuck to it, and do one stroke at a time along the entire length, aiming for a 45° angle and testing after each one.

Perhaps finish with a stroke or two at 22.5° and 67.5° to make it close to round.  It may just feel like a slight burr on the top, in which case start flatter than my previous suggestion.

Especially if it's more than just a slight burr, you might want to start with coarser sandpaper for the first few strokes.  I'd use either paint removal sandpaper or wet/dry silicon carbide paper, rather than basic glasspaper.  My stash of SiC paper is my goto choice for a lot of non-wood sanding; used wet it can provide a nice finish on metals and plastics.

Comment: +1 for the "one stroke at a time". The goal is to _just_ knock down any sharpness while _not_ going all the way through the laminate. I'd also think that something a bit coarser, like a 150 grit would be much more effective and much less frustrating than 320 grit. 320 is so fine that the temptation would be to start rubbing down one area "just to make some progress", then finding out you've gone through the veneer.

Comment: +1 in general, but on this bit, *"On the one here it's clearly that the plastic veneer on the edges is rather thick (about 1.5mm)"* Did I miss the relevant pictures that show this unequivocally? None of the photos I viewed (at full size, on a monitor not a phone screen) were nearly large enough. Plus there is the issue of online product pics being notorious for not being exactly what's delivered.....

Comment: Sorry @Graphus, bad writing on my part: "Here" as in the one I'm sitting at, not the OP's stock image, which might not even be a real photo.

Comment: Good point @FreeMan

Comment: Ah, yes that makes much more sense.